# MySQL raw query: using @var

Tags: mysql, var

I'm trying to rename a list of tables using a constant prefix defined as a @var:

```
SET @p='newprefix_';
RENAME TABLE `oldprefix_tablename1` TO CONCAT(@p, 'tablename1');
RENAME TABLE `oldprefix_tablename2` TO CONCAT(@p, 'tablename2');
```

This syntax is wrong, but I see that:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(@p, 'tablename'); //outputs newprefix_tablename
```

What's the correct way/syntax to use here?

Comment: What is the errror message?

Comment: Its: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select CONCAT(@p, 'tablename1')' at line 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly the way you are trying. As the manual says (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

> User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be
>   used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an
>   identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is
>   expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT.

You have to use prepared statements:

```
SET @p = 'newprefix_';
SET @s = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `oldprefix_tablename1` to ', @p, 'tablename1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```